# Custom Buttons set to "Display in New Window" don't open a new window in Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, page-layout, custom-url

When I add a custom button for use in lightning and set the Behavior to 'Display in New Window', I was expecting it to open in a new tab/window. But when I click it it opens in the current window. This happens for both VisualForce and ULR content sources. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey Ralph, your contributions here are great, but I don't think tagging posts with `wtf` is appropriate. Please refrain from using this tag moving forward. It doesn't add any new information to the post nor make it more searchable.

Comment: @AdrianLarson :( let's be honest salesforce does a lot of crazy stuff, and frankly some issues deserve this flag, and i would actually think if i were a PM at salesforce i'd this flag useful to understand when they're doing really dumb stuff. yes, i'll discontinue, but i whole heartedly disagree that this is inappropriate

Comment: and i would contend that the sledge hammer approach salesforce has taken with lightning that often ignores the existing settings made by administrators deserves this sort of `wtf` call out. i'm not saying descend into the maelstrom of frustration of the idea exchange, but a tag ... this feels like a very restrained and reasonable expression of frustration with salesforce's roadmap planning and inability to fix rather basic bugs

Answer (score 11):

No, it's a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jkrUQAQ). Until it's fixed you'll need to try alternative routes.

> **Custom Buttons for VisualForce pages set to "Display in New Window" should open in a New Window**
>
> **Summary [Lightning Experience] Custom Buttons for VisualForce pages set to "Display in New Window" open within the same tab.  Expected:
>   The custom button for a VisualForce page should open in a new window.**
>
> **Repro This can be repro in any object detail page in Lightning Experience.  Here I use Opp as an example.**
>
> 1. Create a Custom Button in an Opp to a VisualForce page and set its behavior to display in a new window
> 2. Add the Custom Button to the Object Page Layout
> 3. Open an opportunity record in SFX and click on DETAILS
> 4. Find the custom button you created (should be in the page level actions bar/drop-down) and click on it.
>
> **Workaround n/a**

Comment: Still not fixed. :-(